# Perl/Tk GUI for C++ Application

Tags: c++, perl, perltk

I have to do a college project using C++ that requires a GUI. I want to use Perl/Tk for the GUI, but I am not sure how to link the C++ to the Perl. The project requires being able to pass variables back and forth. Could anyone point me in the direction of some good tutorials/books for linking the two, or any ideas on how I should approach the problem as I have never had to link two languages before.

Answer (score 6):

I'm [working](http://www.perlfoundation.org/leon_timmermans_embedding_perl_into_c_applications) on a [library](http://code.google.com/p/libperl/) to make that as simple as possible, but it's still an alpha version.

Answer (score 6):

You can also try [swig](http://www.swig.org).  It's a tool for generating interfaces to several scripting languages from C/C++.

Answer (score 5):

Since Perl is going to be providing the GUI, I'd embed the C++ code into Perl.  Assuming that there's going to be a significant amount of C++ code, I'd put that into a library.  The traditional way of linking that library to Perl is to create a Perl module using XS.  The [Tutorial for writing XSUBs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxstut.html) and [XS language reference manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxs.html) will help with that.

A somewhat easier way may be to use the [Inline](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline) module.  I've used [Inline::C](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline::C) before, and it worked well, but I've never tried [Inline::CPP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline::CPP) (the C++ version).  I see it has [mixed reviews](http://cpanratings.perl.org/dist/Inline-CPP).

Comment: Following-up years later.  Inline::CPP hadn't been maintained since 2003.  In 2011 I started working on it as a co-maintainer, and committed about 135 patches between Nov-2011 and May-2012.  It's in much better shape now.  The RT bug list is down to one lingering wishlist item.  And the CPAN Testers install success ratio is up to the mid-90% range.

Answer (score 1):

If I was tackling this problem I'd be using TCL/TK to create a GUI and then building a TCL extension in C/C++ that can be called from TCL/TK.  This is one of the things that TCL/TK is really good at (other dynamic languages can do this as well but I like TCL/TK).  You create a shared libray (.so on Unix or .dll on windows) with the C++ bits and they get imported as commands into TCL when you load the library.

Swig, which has already been mentioned, is a tool that helps automate the wrapping process, it can take your C++ code and create a wrapper that allows it to be loaded into a number languages such as TCL, Perl, Python, Ruby ...

Start at http://www.tcl.tk/ for lots of informtion an TCL and TK.

Answer (score 0):

if its a small project, its probably not worth the investment to spend lots of time getting the two languages to talk.  you might consider using a more appropriate tool.  C# will talk to C++ with a lot less pain.